# MKAnnotationView not detecting if button or title touched

Tags: mapkit, mkannotationview

Hello my problem is that this code:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    if control is UIButton {
        if (control as! UIButton).buttonType == .DetailDisclosure{removeAnnotation()}
        else{performSegueWithIdentifier("edit", sender: nil)}
    }
}
```

seems not to work as it should. The problem is that `removeAnnotation()` is called always even when I touch title, not the button. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Add the info right button in the

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? { 

        // add button here, i.e. 

        let btn = UIButton(type: .Custom)
            btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
            btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "info"), forState: .Normal)
            annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn

        // ... other required code
}
```

Then within the

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

    if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
        print("Tap")
    }
}
```

Comment: 'func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView) {
        if (view.annotation as! MyAnnotation).editable == false{
            view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = nil
        }
        else {
            view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .InfoLight)} ' I tried to do it like you suggested but it works just the same

Comment: I can't add it in 'mapView(mapView: viewForAnnotation)' because not every annotationView should have that button. Changing frame doesn't make a difference.

Comment: You can filter it, i.e if a certain kind of pin should have a button then add one. I do it with my apps. Different pins have different accessory buttons.

Comment: I would have to use multiple reuse identifiers, so I made it different way but thats not what my problem is.